# Windows terminal/Console/shell in Vi mode?

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, vim, emulation

I'm a big fan of VIM and I use `VI mode` for my terminal in Mac/Ubuntu. It's very easy to set a Vi Mode in Unix OS: simply put `set editing-mode vi set keymap vi-command` into `~/.inputrc`.

However, my current company forces me to use Windows, and I would like to know if there are any Windows Shell Emulator that supports Vi Mode?

Comment: Those commands should go in `~/.inputrc` not `~/.vimrc`

Comment: @FDinoff sorry typo.. fixed

Comment: Also I don't think `set keymap vi-command` is necessary. It just allows you to map different keys in command mode (So useless if you don't use any other mappings)

Comment: @FDinoff I've further referred to the guide: http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-inputrc.html. It seems that vi-command is the default setting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would recommend you to try PowerShell version 3+ and [PSReadLine](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine) module.
It does support vi mode as of version 1.2, and emacs mode for a while now (it was there already when I started playing with it).

Comment: If you look on github, you'll find a fork of PSReadLine with vi mode support - there is a pull request that I'll get around to eventually.

Comment: I used this to make ViM my default edit mode: `"\`nSet-PSReadlineOption -EditMode Vi" | add-content $profile`

Answer (score 1):

Same here, long time MacOS/Ubuntu user switching to Windows. Most of the stuff can be done perfectly under ***WSL***, but still need *powershell* for some other teams' scripts. For VI mode in PS:

1. as BartekB mentioned, you can install the PSReadLine:

> Install-Module PsReadline -Scope CurrentUser

2. Then open **config** file(PATH is typically under the `$PROFILE`, which points to `C:\Users\YourUserName\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`). you can use notepad or nvim to open it:

> notepad $PROFILE

3. Then you can add the below line to its configuration:

> Set-PSReadlineOption -EditMode vi

4. open a new session, OR use `. $PROFILE` to reload config for your current session.

now you can use `esc` to enter Normal mode or `v` to use visual mode.

Answer (score -2):

Vim is also available for Windows.
Check out : http://www.vim.org/

On Windows, the customization of Vim is very similar, you can use the file $HOME/_vimrc to store your commands and settings.

Vim on Windows can be launched directly from a traditional command prompt (cmd.exe) or from a Powershell Console.

Comment: Thx for reply. By "vi-mode" I mean this: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_vi_shortcuts_in_terminal